# what is the correct way to segregate two columns in a csv where the data is mixed up?

Tags: python, dataframe, text-mining

I want all the JEL classifications in one column (called `classification`) and keywords in another column (called `keywords`), the sample data is below. Here `k/c` is the first column and `c/k` the next

```
                                                 k/c  \
0  Keywords\r\nLegal systemsInstitutional environ...   
1                       JEL classification\r\nG30G34   
2                JEL classifications\r\nG38J21J30P26   
3         JEL classification codes\r\nG30G34G38K21L4   
4                       JEL classification\r\nG11G23   
5                                                NaN   
6                                                NaN   
7                                                NaN   
8                                                NaN   
9                      JEL classifications\r\nG24G23
```

```
                                                 c/k  
0                 JEL classification\r\nG21G24G32G34  
1  Keywords\r\nDirector electionsFamily firmsGove...  
2  Keywords\r\nPolitical connection disruptionsLa...  
3  Keywords\r\nMergers and acquisitions (M&A)Acqu...  
4  Keywords\r\nAdvisory ratesFund governanceAgenc...  
5  Keywords\r\nHometown connectionsTrade creditCE...  
6                                                NaN  
7  Keywords\r\nOperating riskInvestment riskCredi...  
8                                                NaN  
9  Keywords\r\nHerd behaviourBuyoutPrivate equity...
```

```
df["classification"] = []
df["keywords"] = []

for i in df[["k/c"]]:
    if i == Keywords:
        df["keywords"].append(i)
    elif i == JEL:
        df["classification"].append(i)

print(["classification"])
print(["keywords"])
```

Comment: Hi Pranav, welcome to SO, take some time to read [mcve] and then reformat your question. No one here knows your issues, or variables (such as Keywords) you'll need to provide a well formatted question that anyone will be able to understand. Also post your JEL dataset as text and not an image.

Comment: @Datanovice I have posted an edited question with the data in the text format, please have a look at it

Comment: Hi Pranav, your text is still an image, and you still haven't delcared your `Keywords` variable.

Comment: Hi @Datanovice just updated

Comment: can you try `print(df.head(10))` and copy the output paste it here.

Comment: hi @Datanovice just posted the output